# Conditional Replacement in LOG file

Tags: regex, perl, formatting

I'm working on a way to automate the formatting of a file. My goal is to take a file like this:

```
12154389,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154389.JPG,Y,,,
12154390,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154390.JPG,,,,
12154391,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154391.JPG,Y,,,
12154392,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154392.JPG,,,,
12154393,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154393.JPG,,,,
12154394,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154394.JPG,Y,,,
12154395,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154395.JPG,,,,
12154396,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154396.JPG,,,,
12154397,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154397.JPG,Y,,,
12154398,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154398.JPG,Y,,,
12154399,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154399.JPG,,,,
12154400,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154400.JPG,,,,
```

and convert it to this format:

```
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154389.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154390.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154391.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154392.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154393.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154394.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154395.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154396.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154397.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154398.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154399.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154400.JPG;
```

This is the code I'm working with right now (I know there has to be a better way to approach this, but I'm struggling with the logic):

```
$condition0 = ".*/\\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\/";
open my $in,  '<',  "C:\\Users\\bhn\\Documents\\Scripting\\Perl\\sample.opt"              or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "C:\\Users\\bhn\\Documents\\Scripting\\Perl\\working.opt"  or die "Can't write new file: $!";


while( <$in> )
    {

s/.JPG,,,,/.JPG;/g;         #replace if not Y break
s/.JPG;\r/.JPG/g if /$condition0/;  #remove extra new lines
s/JPG,Y,,,\n/JPG,Y,;/g;     #remove ,,,, from non-Y breaks
s/(.*),,C:/C:/g;            #gets rid of image key and ,,


print $out $_;
}

close $out;`
```

The ultimate goal here is to force all lines without a Y break onto the previous line with a Y break, then replace all instances of either ,,,, or ,Y,,, with a semicolon. The beginning of the file features a key and two commas, which are also being removed.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or pointers for me. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i completely followed your question however I have produced the below code which given your input produces the output you are looking for, let me know if i have missed anything and i will try to update.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
        chomp(); #remove new lines
        print "\n" if /,Y,,,$/; #if we have the Y marker then we should be starting on new line
        s/^\d+,,(.*),Y?,,,$/$1;/; #now remove the image key and take just the path, and replace end commas with semi colon.
        print $_; #print the line
}
print "\n";


__DATA__
12154389,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154389.JPG,Y,,,
12154390,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154390.JPG,,,,
12154391,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154391.JPG,Y,,,
12154392,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154392.JPG,,,,
12154393,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154393.JPG,,,,
12154394,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154394.JPG,Y,,,
12154395,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154395.JPG,,,,
12154396,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154396.JPG,,,,
12154397,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154397.JPG,Y,,,
12154398,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154398.JPG,Y,,,
12154399,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154399.JPG,,,,
12154400,,C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154400.JPG,,,,
```

This produces the output

```
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154389.JPG;C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154390.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154391.JPG;C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154392.JPG;C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154393.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154394.JPG;C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154395.JPG;C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154396.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154397.JPG;
C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154398.JPG;C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154399.JPG;C:\Users\bhn\Documents\Scripting\Perl\Sample_Images\12154400.JPG;
```

Comment: @Ben Horner - what type of system are you running this on, i have tested the script on windows and linux and it works as i have shown

Answer (score 0):

@Chris

I'm trying to modify this so the input can be pulled from a file, then printed to a separate output file. When I use the following, all lines are combined into one line:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in,  '<',  "C:\\Users\\bhn\\Documents\\Scripting\\Perl\\sample.opt"    or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "C:\\Users\\bhn\\Documents\\Scripting\\Perl\\working.opt" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

while (<$in>) {
    chomp(); #remove new lines
    print "\n" if /,Y,,,$/; #if we have the Y marker then we should be   starting on new line
    s/^\d+,,(.*),Y?,,,$/$1;/; #now remove the image key and take just the     path, and replace end commas with semi colon.
    print $out $_; #print the line
}
print "\n";
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?